# Generic EntityById pipe nest js

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typescript-generics, mikro-orm

I'm Trying to Implement a **Generic EntityById Pipe** Similar to the one From the Nest.js Documentation's [Pipe Transformation UseCase](https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes#transformation-use-case) `UserByIdPipe`, for that I can implement this simply like this

```
@Injectable()
export class UserByIdPipe implements PipeTransform<string, Promise<User>> {
  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  async transform(value: string): Promise<User> {
    const user = await this.userService.findOne(value);
    if (!user) {
      throw new EntityNotFoundException(value);
    }
    return user;
  }
}
```

But The same as a genericPipe Which does the exact same thing but will be generic for All Entities, I can scratch up something like this (I'm using mikro-orm)

```
@Injectable()
export class EntityByUuidPipe<T extends object>
  implements PipeTransform<string, Promise<T>>
{
  constructor(private readonly repo: EntityRepository<T>) {}

  async transform(id: string): Promise<T> {
    const entity = await this.repo.findOneOrFail(id);
    return entity;
  }
}
```

But **the problem that I'm Facing for Generic implementation** is that I cannot pass the user repository  as the constructor Argument since I'm getting  userRepository injected via Nest.js DI.

```
  @Get(':id')
  findOne(@Param('id', new ParseUUIDPipe(), new EntityByUuidPipe(UserRepository)) user: User) {
    return user;
  }
```

I feel like Im almost there with the implementation but missing a small thing, Can anyone please take a look at this and suggest an Implementation for this?

Thank you

Comment: Don't use repositories, use the `EntityManager` instead. Repositories are just a thin layer on top of it.

Comment: You obviously need to set the entity type somewhere - if the decorator should be generic, you will need to pass that to its parameters probably, it depends how you want to use it.